# How to bypass the login screen in a CakePHP app (jSlate)?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, autologin

I'm having problems integrating a CakePHP app (jSlate) into a bespoke non-Cake web application.  All the alternative authentication scripts I've seen simply change the behaviour of the login form, in other words the login form still appears, and asks for username and password, but these are authenticated against an alternative source, such as LDAP.

What I actually want is for no login screen to appear at all.  Instead I want a very simple behaviour:

1. Detect if user is already logged in to third party app.
2. If yes, automatically log them in to the CakePHP app (in this case jSlate).
3. If no, redirect to the third party app login screen.

Is there a tutorial for a CakePHP authentication along these lines?  Or does someone know how to do this?  I've worked out how to do part 3, but this behaviour is kind of useless without parts 1 and 2...

Comment: How would that detection work? Is there any data exchange possible? Any token or cookie that can be evaluated?

Comment: @deceze Yes its in a cookie. I can write that code, I just need to know where to put it.  I've created custom a auth controller for example.  But do I need a custom user controller?  Or a custom security controller?  And what method do I override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this into your `AppController::beforeFilter`:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if (!$this->Auth->user()) {
        // if no user is currently logged in

        if ($this->Cookie->read(...)) {
        // or
        if ($_COOKIE[...]) {
        // or whatever else you want to detect

            $this->redirect('http://some.external/login/service');
        }
    }
}
```

This external login service would then presumably redirect the user back to your Cake app at some point with some sort of token. You just need to define a publicly accessible action (no auth required) which it can redirect back to. In that action, you check all the tokens you need and can then "manually" authenticate the user:

```
$user = $this->User->find(/* find your Cake user by some id */);
if ($user) {
    $this->Auth->login($user['User']['id']);
}
```

Congratulations, the user is now logged in as if he'd used a login form and has a valid Cake session.

Comment: Presumably there is an 'else' between the if and the redirect?  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What I mean is that you need to check for whatever it is you need to check from the external auth service, and if you determine that the user should be redirected to the external service for login, you redirect him. Else you do nothing.

Comment: Okay, but what does it mean to 'define a publicly accessible action'? I'm slightly lost as to where that second bit of code would go...

Comment: How is that third party authentication supposed to work? I'm assuming something along the lines of OpenID or Oauth, where the user is redirected back to a pre-defined URL when authentication is successful. When the user is redirected back there, he's still not authenticated as pertains to Cake. So Cake should not reject him because he's not authenticated yet, which means you need to have something that's accessible without being logged in. In Cake terms: `$this->Auth->allow('some_action')`.

Comment: No, its a full integration.  The CakeApp is in a subfolder of the non-Cake app on the same website.  So I should be able to just check for the pressence of the session variable and auto loggin or not.  So can I skip that bit and do it all in AppController::beforeFilter?

Comment: Well, yes. In that case the basic idea is to check *on each request* whether the user is logged in or not and whether there may be an opportunity to log him in before continuing with the request as usual. You do that in `AppController::beforeFilter`.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I'm past the login screen now.  Got more errors, but if I can't solve those I guess they are a different question...